# Different enumitem \ref, \cref results to item for direct enumerate vs. defined newlist

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem, cleveref

Using the `enumitem` package, I'm trying to cross-reference an item in an `enumerate` list.

1. When I use `\ref` to cross-reference an item, I get the same, satisfactory, result no matter  whether I create the `enumerate` list directly in the body of the source, on the one hand, or use a `\newlist` / `\setlist` definition of the environment in the preamble. But why do I not get the same results in those two situations when I use `\cref` instead of `\ref`?
2. Why don't the `\cref` results work in either situation?

This example, showing all 4 combinations of `\ref`, `\cref`, preamble-defined enumerate, and directly-defined enumerate, uses just the `*` versions of the commands; but similar results occur with the unstarred versions.

**Situation — `\newlist` `\setlist` with `\ref*` :**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\newlist{romcases}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[romcases,1]{%
    label=\sffamily{Case (\roman*):},
    ref=\normalfont{Case (\roman*)},
    wide,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt
}    
\crefname{romcases}{Case}{Case}
\Crefname{romcases}{Case}{Case}

\begin{document}

We distinguish two cases.

\begin{romcases}

\item \label{case:abequal} 
$a = b$. Now we see that\dots 

\item\label{case:abnotequal}
 $a \neq b$. In contrast to \ref*{case:abequal}, in this case \dots 

\end{romcases}

\bigskip

\textbf{\emph{NOTE:} Output as expected.}

\end{document}
```

[image: newlist & \ref*]

**Situation — direct `\enumerate`with `\ref*` :**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

We distinguish two cases.

\begin{enumerate}[%
  label=\textsf{Case (\alph*):},ref=\normalfont{Case (\roman*)},
  wide,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt]

\item \label{case:abequal} 
$a = b$.

Now we see that\dots 

\item\label{case:abnotequal}
 $a \neq b$. 
 In contrast to \ref*{case:abequal}, in this case \dots 

\end{enumerate}

\bigskip

\textbf{\emph{NOTE:} Output \emph{OK}.}

\end{document}
```

[image: direct enumerate & \ref*]

**Situation — `\newlist` `\setlist` with `\cref*` :**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\newlist{romcases}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[romcases,1]{%
    label=\sffamily{Case (\roman*):},
    ref=\normalfont{Case (\roman*)},
    wide,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt
}    
\crefname{romcases}{Case}{Case}
\Crefname{romcases}{Case}{Case}

\begin{document}

We distinguish two cases.

\begin{romcases}

\item \label{case:abequal} 
$a = b$. Now we see that\dots 

\item\label{case:abnotequal}
 $a \neq b$.  In contrast to \cref*{case:abequal}, in this case \dots 

\end{romcases}

\bigskip

\textbf{\emph{NOTE:} Output \emph{NOT} as expected.}

\end{document}
```

[image: newlist & \cref*]

**Situation — direct `\enumerate`with `\cref*` :**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

We distinguish two cases.

\begin{enumerate}[%
  label=\textsf{Case (\alph*):},ref=\normalfont{Case (\roman*)},
  wide,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt]

\item \label{case:abequal} 
$a = b$. Now we see that\dots 

\item\label{case:abnotequal}
 $a \neq b$.  In contrast to \cref*{case:abequal}, in this case \dots 

\end{enumerate}

\bigskip

\textbf{\emph{NOTE:} Output \emph{NOT} as expected.}

\end{document}
```

[image: direct enumerate & \cref*]

Comment: In the `romcases` case, the level-1 counter variable is named `romcasesi`, not `romcases`. Correct the first argument of `\crefname` and `\Crefname` and you'll be fine.

Comment: In your fourth example, the counter that's used for cross-referencing level-1 enumerated items is called `enumi`. The `cleveref` package prefixes the string "Item" to objects associated with the `enumi` counter. Because you also have the instruction `ref=\normalfont{Case (\roman*)}`, it is actually *fully expected* to get "Item Case (i)" as the output of `\cref{case:abequal}`. If you want to keep `ref=\normalfont{Case (\roman*)}` and wish to use `\cref`, you should run `\crefname{enumi}{}{}` to override the default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you define a new enumerated list environment called `romcases` via a `\newlist` instruction, the counter associated with level-1 items is called `romcasesi`. Similarly, the counter associated with level-2 romcases items is called `romcasesii`, etc.

If you're going to use the macros of the `cleveref` package to create "clever" cross-references, I suggest you specify just `ref=\roman*` in argument of `\setlist[romcases,1]`; note: no string label "Case", and no parentheses. Then, use `\creflabelformat`, `\crefname` and `\Crefname` directives to specify how `\cref` and friends should format and typeset the cross-references. This approach will give you maximum flexibility -- which will come in handy when you start including multiple objects in a single `\cref` statement and expect `cleveref` to handle the sorting of arguments automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\newlist{romcases}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[romcases,1]{
    label={\sffamily Case (\roman*):},
    ref=\roman*, % if to be used with \cref, don't provide label string or parentheses
    wide,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt} 
\creflabelformat{romcasesi}{#2\textup{(#1)}#3} % note presence of parentheses
\crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases} % singular and plural forms of text labels
\Crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}

\begin{document}
We distinguish two cases:
\begin{romcases}
\item \label{case:abequal} $a = b$. Now we see that\dots 
\item\label{case:abnotequal} $a \neq b$.  In contrast to \cref{case:abequal}, \dots 
\end{romcases}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand the comment "if to be used with \cref, don't provide a label string": if I don't include a `label` string, I get an immediate "Undefined error" when running `latex` on the source. did you mean, rather, not to provide a `ref` in the `setlist`? But then I get output  for the link as "Case Case (i)".

Comment: @murray - The comment means: If you're going to create cross-references with `\cref`, don't write `ref=\normalfont{Case (\roman*)},` (as you did in your example code), i.e. omit the "Case"  label string: `ref=(\roman*). (`\normalfont` is the default.) `\cref` provides a label string of its own -- the one specified in the `\crefname` instruction. I recommend providing just a counter number because it allows `\cref` to take multiple arguments, which will be sorted and compressed if they're numeric; if you pass general strings, `\cref` can't provide the sorting and compressing functionality.

Comment: @murray - I've updated my answer slightly. If you're going to use the macros of the `cleveref` package to create cross-references, I now suggest that you provide a pure (roman) counter for the `ref=` part in the argument of `\setlist`. Then, use `\creflabelformat{romcasesi}{...}` and `\crefname{romcasesi}{...}{...}` statements. This will give you maximum flexibility.